# How to identify type by hash value?

Tags: c#, serialization, hash, udp, client-server

So I have basic UDP server, I've implemented some things like restoring byte array exactly how it was send by client (if it was retrieved out of order). Bassicaly, I have client, server and shared class library with types, objects of which could be send from client to server and vice versa. So now I came with idea to serialize some objects and send to server/client. But I need to know what type of object was recieved to deserialize it properly. Two ideas came into mind to solve this problem:

- Make a "handshake". Send data about what object will be send after, its length, class name, etc. And after it retrive actual data and deserialize it. I know to do it, but since it's UDP, this "handshake" could be lost  and I need to re-ask it, so there is pretty complicated logic and network over-usage, but I know how to implement this.
- And second one is identifing type by some hash value. So client sends data which contains hash value of type and piece of data (I will only send my own type's objects, so no need to implement this for C# and Framework types), and I need to determine type by this hash value and server could deserealize it properly.

So any ideas, how to implement this? It will be perfect if I manage to avoid reflection because it's slow (I don't care about huge switch statement if it works faster)

Comment: I'm assuming you have your own protocol as you're sending bytes over UDP. So I would say have a reserved byte or two that you can use to determine what type of object you're sending/receiving. It's up to you.

Comment: No, just standart [binary serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) at this moment

Comment: the idea still stands: you can send a serialized Type right before the object to signal what's incoming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this just today for a prototype I was working on. I defined my message stream thus:

First 4 bytes: length of the assembly-qualified type name as an Int32.

Next n bytes (where n is given by the first 4 bytes): assembly-qualified name of the type.

Rest of the message: the serialized object

It worked like a charm.

Comment: And type casting to needed type using reflection?

Comment: @Dantix Casting is a static compile-time concept; you can't cast a type that you only know at run time.  What situation do you imagine would require the cast?  If you're calling a method that takes a more specific type than `object`, you're going to have to call that method using reflection.  When you call `Invoke` on a `MethodInfo`, the arguments are passed in an `object` array; there's a run-time type check, but no static cast.

Comment: Also, added int value of message length to check if retrieved full message or only part of it

Comment: @Dantix good thinking.  I'm glad my project was just a prototype :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just make the object type part of the object data and send them both using precisely the same logic. Don't try to handle them separately at the network level.

Comment: I should know type before deseriliazing it :)

Comment: Right, but that's after receiving it. So it's not an issue to the network layers.